# strange values of get rusage.maxrss on macOS and Linux

Tags: linux, macos, go, rusage

Currently i'm writing online judgment system on golang.
To detect user program memory usage i've decided to analyze `cmd.ProcessState.SysUsage()` and check `Rusage.Maxrss`.
Now i'm confused, because when i try to run this on my mac result of `Rusage.Maxrss` call is strange

Here is code, that i've runned on macOS and Linux (it's simplified, this code call `Getrusage()` of current process)
And there're results i've gotten:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "syscall"
)

func main() {
    rusage := syscall.Rusage{}
    pageSize := syscall.Getpagesize()
    if err := syscall.Getrusage(syscall.RUSAGE_SELF, &rusage); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("page size: %d\nrusage.Maxrss: %d\n", pageSize, rusage.Maxrss)
}
```

And following results i've gotten

- MacOS:

  ```
  go run test.go 
  page size: 4096
  rusage.Maxrss: 2007040
  ```
- Linux/Ubuntu-18.04:

  ```
  go run test.go                     
  page size: 4096
  rusage.Maxrss: 17580
  ```

Can you explain why it returns such big value? As i've seen macOS manual and linux man pages: rusage.Maxrss
(or `rusage.ru_maxrss` from `C` language) is counted in kilobytes, so on macOS my code used ~2GB of memory 
when on Linux it used only ~20MB?

And is this a good decision to measure memory used by user program with `rusage.Maxrss`
or there are better approach?

Comment: On my Macs, the `getrusage()` man page says: "_ru_maxrss_    the maximum resident set size utilized (**in bytes**)" (emphasis added).

Comment: Thank you very much @ken-thomases, i've seen [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man2/getrusage.2.html]) and haven't seen local man. It's my fault.

Comment: You're welcome. I don't know if that's a difference between macOS and iOS or if it's something that changed over time and that link, being in the unmaintained documentation archive, shows the earlier man page. (And, if it did change over time, it might be just that the man page was incorrect and has been corrected; or, it might be that the behavior of the OS changed and the man page accurately reflects the behavior.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On my Macs, the `getrusage()` man page says: "*ru_maxrss* the maximum resident set size utilized (**in bytes**)" (emphasis added). That seems to make sense of your results.

The [iOS man page in Apple's legacy documentation archive](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man2/getrusage.2.html) to which you were referring does say the units are kilobytes. It's not clear if that's due to different behaviors between iOS and macOS or an error in the man page that's since been corrected. It's a shame that Apple doesn't keep maintained man pages online.

Answer (score 0):

As best I can tell (from testing plus manual pages)

- On FreeBSD, OpenBSD, & NetBSD maxrss is in KBytes but ixrss is in Bytes.
- On Macos since at least 10.11(El Capitan) maxrss is in Bytes but
  ixrss is in KBytes
- On MacOS X 10.6 ... ?? maxrss and ixrss are in KBytes
- On Linux (since 2.6.32) maxrss is in KBytes and ixrss is undefined.